# Monitor mutex, seamaphor in all process

Tags: c#, .net, monitoring, mutex, semaphore

I need to list out all the mutex/semaphores in all the processes.

I need it in C# application for monitoring. I am not able to find any reference on msdn/google.

Any starting point will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

See the [SysInternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/default) tools suite, particularly [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645).

Comment: I want to enumerate into c# application.